# WebAPI Model Binding from JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, model-binding, durandal

I am creating an application using Durandal, with WebAPI as the server. I have a KendoUI grid that displays the data from the server correctly and functions properly until the POST or PUT methods are called. Here is my GET method:
[image]

and you can see that that data binds to the UI (used the [data-bind extensibility](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/KendoUI/) in Durandal to change to kendo bindings):
[image]

Then I edit the data in the Grid and it passes the changes inside the request to the server as you can see in this Fiddler result:
[image]

On the server side I cannot get the data that is passed from the client to bind to anything I place as a parameter for the method on the POST or PUT. 
[image]

I realize this is a couple different technologies to troubleshoot (e.g. Durandal, KnockoutJs, Kendo DataBinding, and WebAPI) but I think the fundamentals are working, the data is retrieved and bound to the UI and it is posted back when changed, but the WebAPI endpoint cannot bind to the data.

How can I get the passed "models" array to bind through the ModelBinding structure in WebAPI?

UPDATE- Here is the helpful JSFiddle that gave me the correct Content-Type to add: http://jsfiddle.net/Xhrrj/1/

`new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
            read: {
                type: "POST",
                url: "../cccs/service.svc/SupplierSearch",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json'...`

this is coming from the Telerik forum [here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/framework/data-source/problem-with-datasource-post-request-for-read-operation.aspx)

Comment: Based on the example fiddler request you are sending back the data but not in the right format so Web.API cannot consume it. So the problem is with the way how you serialize the data. So please post the code of your save changes method, or where you create the `put` request.

Comment: It looks as if it was mixing up form-urlencoded with json format - it is sending `models=` and then urlencoded JSON objects follow.

Comment: @nemesv, I am using KendoUI's javascript functions, here is a snippet that i think might be helpful: parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                }
                            } - link http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/grid/editing -- also reading this, might be a way to change the json model but not sure -- http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/datasource/overview

Comment: @Joanna, you were the closest to correct, the http headers were formatting the string to this-- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8. By placing the following in my javascript object for the PUT and POST I got the correct data through -- contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8". Give an answer and I will give it to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks as if it was mixing up `form-urlencoded` with `json` format - if you lookat the decoded string it is sending `models=` and then urlencoded JSON objects follow.

Comment: the http headers were formatting the string to this-- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8. By placing the following in my javascript object for the PUT and POST I got the correct data through -- contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I think that your PUT end point declaration needs to look like this:

```
[HttpPut]
public void Put([FromBody]IEnumerable<Product> models) { }
```

So you need the FromBody attribute because your product array is in the body (I think?) and not in the url of the request.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for responding, but your answer didn't change the binding values, it was actually that I had to explicitly specify the Content-Type header to get the JSON data to bind in the API methods.